# Expresión lambda en Grid.column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Quiero hacer una expresión lambda en un grid colum y no puedo.

Creo una tabla y esto funciona.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     @foreach (var m in Model)
      {
          <tr>
              <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => m.Id)</td>
              <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => m.PromocionValor.FirstOrDefault(pv => pv.ModalidadId == 1).Valor)</td>                       
          </tr>
      }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

No me vale lo anterior para poder paginar las filas de la tabla y pruebo a hacer lo siguiente:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(canSort: false);
grid.Bind(Model, autoSortAndPage: false, rowCount:  (int)ViewBag.TotalfilasContadas);
    var columnas = new List<WebGridColumn>()
{
grid.Column(@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Id).ToString(),"Id"),
grid.Column(@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => (m.PromocionValor.FirstOrDefault(pv => pv.ModalidadId == 1).Valor).ToString(), "TR")
};
```

No funciona porque el modelo en algunos casos no tiene PromocionValor o si la tiene, esta no tiene ModalidadId == 1.

¿Cómo lo haríais vosotros?

Answer (score 0):

Yo enviaría el modelo ya procesado, el problema con la forma en que lo estas haciendo mas allá de que funcione o no es que estas mezclando lo que para algunos como yo considerarían lógica de negocio en la vista, y esto no debería ser así.

Como lo haría yo, seria enviar el objeto o la colección ya lista y preparada para 
solo ser mostrada en el cliente. y delegar esa lógica a la capa de negocio si existe o en su defecto al controlador. de esta forma podrás controlar lo que quieres mostrar o tener quizás un valor por defecto si este no viene como comentas.

Saludos!